# Получение ID стикера VK

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Хотелось бы узнать метод/код для получения ID стикера в VK. Знаю, что его можно получить через HTML код (https://chaldaev.pro/?p=817 может кому то нужно), но хотелось бы автоматизировать процесс получением ID стикера кодом.

Answer (score 0):

насколько я помню, достаточно воспользоваться методом получения информации о сообщении (messages.getById, messages.getByConversationMessageId).
внутри вернувшегося вам json результата, в поле attachments должна находится вся информация касательно стикера